# How to test if the snapshot of a publication in transactional replication is valid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-replication

I have removed some articles of my publication in transactional replication.
I use the script below, and contrary to what I have found in documentation, it does not invalidate the snapshot of that publication.

I normally test this by running the snapshot agent, which, after about 12 seconds, tells me that there is no need to run a full snapshot.

How can I test whether the snapshot is good, without running it?

I don't want to run it, because if it is not good, I don't want to stop it in the middle, and I don't want to run it during the office hours.

thanks and regards

Marcelo

```
-- the script to remove an article from the replication is: (1) and (2) below:
-- to be run at the publisher (in this case SERVER MYSERVER - DATABASE MYDATABASE
-- (1)
--use [MYDATABASE]
--exec sp_dropsubscription @publication = N'MYPUBLICATION', @article = N'tblTaxTransaction', @subscriber = N'all', @destination_db = N'all'
--GO

-- (2)
--use [MYDATABASE]
--exec sp_droparticle @publication = N'MYPUBLICATION', @article = N'tblTaxTransaction', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1
--GO



--[ @force_invalidate_snapshot = ] force_invalidate_snapshot
--Acknowledges that the action taken by this stored procedure may invalidate an existing snapshot. 
--force_invalidate_snapshot is a bit, with a default of 0.
--0 specifies that changes to the article do not cause the snapshot to be invalid. 
--If the stored procedure detects that the change does require a new snapshot, an error occurs 
--and no changes are made.

--1 specifies that changes to the article may cause the snapshot to be invalid, 
--and if there are existing subscriptions that would require a new snapshot, 
--gives permission for the existing snapshot to be marked as obsolete and a new snapshot generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any answer for this, possibly the answer is that there is no way of doing it through T-SQL, however,
I have learned for a fact that having immediate_sync and allow_anonymous options setting to false helps in not having to generate a snapshot every time you add or remove articles to the publication.

--> checking immediate_sync and allow_anonymous options

If they are set to 1 then every time you add a new article it will cause the entire snapshot to be applied.

You can disable them using sp_changepublication:

```
Exec sp_changepublication
@publication = ' publication db'
@property=N'allow_anonymous',
@value='false'
Go

Exec sp_changepublication
@publication = ' publication db'
@property=N'immediate_sync',
@value='false'
go
```